# Need a PowerShell script that copies files from the current dir that the script is run from to another location

Tags: powershell, scripting, copy

I was asked to write a PowerShell script that they can package in with their build updates. They will complete a build that gets dropped to a folder (say \server\build\release1.1.2). We need a script that takes all the files/folders from that folder and copies them to the appropriately named locations.

I need the script to also read the # of the current build from the folder title and create that same # build folder when it copies. Easy enough to that however I need the references to be all dynamic, so when that Release1.1.3 comes out wecan drop the same script into there and it will copy all the files to the appropriate directories (and create them if they don't exist).

Comment: Why wouldn't the Copy-Item cmdlet do exactly what you want?

Comment: Could you post what you already have? That makes it easier adapting it. From what you write it sounds very straightforward and I wonder how to get that wrong

Answer (score 0):

This script should get you started. Run it to see an example of the values it produces.

```
# variable name chosen based on the automatic variable available to PowerShell Modules
$PSScriptRoot = ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path | Split-Path | Resolve-Path).ProviderPath

$BuildName = $PSScriptRoot | Split-Path -Leaf

@"
This script file is located at:
$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)

The folder this script file is in is:
$PSScriptRoot

The name of the folder this script file is in is:
$BuildName

To copy files you might do this:
Copy-Item -Path `$PSScriptRoot\* -Destination C:\Install\`$BuildName -Recurse
"@
```